Godot Adding Dash Ability To Player As An Independent Scene
I'm working on a project using the Godot game engine
the project includes player movement and dashing ability
I have a script for the CharacterBody2D that handles player movement and dashing
but I want to make dashing ability independent
can I make another scene with Node node and add a script to it that handles the dashing ability?
if yes, how do I implement it?
do I access the player through dash script or what?
I'm going to share with you the code on CharacterBody2D
if you know how can I split the code into two files, one for player movement and the other for dashing ability please let me know
extends CharacterBody2D

@onready var animated_sprite = $AnimatedSprite2D
@onready var timer = $Timer

@export_category("Properties")
@export var player_speed: int = 500
@export var gravity: int = 1200
@export var jump_strength: int = -400
@export var max_jump_times: int = 2
@export var dash_speed: int = 1500
@export var dash_duration: float = 0.2

var dashing: bool = false
var dash_timer: float = 0.0
var can_dash: bool = true
var jump_count: int = 0
var was_on_floor: bool = false
var play_fall_shake: bool = false


func _process(delta):
    handle_player_movement(delta)


func handle_player_movement(delta):
    var direction = get_movement_axis()
    
    # Handle Gravity
    if not is_on_floor():
        velocity.y += gravity * delta
        play_fall_shake = true
    else:
        can_dash = true
        if not was_on_floor:
            handle_jump_and_camera_shake()
    
    # Handle Dashing
    if dashing:
        velocity.y = 0
        velocity.x = dash_speed * (1 if animated_sprite.flip_h == false else -1)
        dash_timer -= delta
        if dash_timer <= 0:
            dashing = false
    else:
        velocity.x = direction.x * player_speed
    
    was_on_floor = is_on_floor()
    manage_animations(direction)
    move_and_slide()


func manage_animations(direction):
    # Handle Sprite Face Direction
    if direction.x == -1:
        animated_sprite.flip_h = true
    if direction.x == 1:
        animated_sprite.flip_h = false
    
    # Handle 
    if direction.x != 0:
        animated_sprite.play("walk")
    else:
        animated_sprite.play("idle")
    
    # Handle Jump Animation
    if velocity.y and not dashing:
        animated_sprite.play("jump_start")
    
    if dashing:
        animated_sprite.play("dash")

func handle_jump_and_camera_shake():
    jump_count = 0
    if play_fall_shake:
        var camera = get_tree().get_first_node_in_group("camera") as Camera2D
        if camera:
            camera.apply_jump_fall_shaking()
            play_fall_shake = false


func get_movement_axis():
    var x_movement = (Input.get_action_strength("move_right") - Input.get_action_strength("move_left") if not dashing else 0)
    
    return Vector2(x_movement, 0)


func _input(event):
    if event.is_action_pressed("jump"):
        if can_jump():
            velocity.y = jump_strength
            jump_count += 1
    
    if event.is_action_pressed("dash") and not dashing and can_dash:
        start_dash()
 

func can_jump():
    return is_on_floor() or jump_count < max_jump_times


func start_dash():
    can_dash = false
    dashing = true
    dash_timer = dash_duration



I think what you're looking for is state machines
